# Como saber qual o objeto ao qual pertence outro objeto?

Tags: java, algoritmo

Tentei arranjar um exemplo mais simples, então tenho uma Pessoa que tem uma lista de Carros.
Tendo eu um Carro c1, como saberei a quem pertence?

```
    public class Pessoa {

        private String nome;
        private ListaCarros carros;

        public Pessoa(String nome, ListaCarros carros) {
            this.nome = nome;
            this.carros = carros;
        }
    }

    public class ListaCarros {

        private HashMap<String, Carro> listaCarros;

        public ListaCarros() {
            listaCarros = new HashMap<>();
        }

        public void adicionar(Carro carro) {
            listaCarros.put(carro.getMatricula(), carro);
        } 

    }

    public class Carro {

        private String matricula;

        public Carro(String matricula) {
            this.matricula = matricula;
        }  

        public String getMatricula() {
            return matricula;
        }

    }
    public class Teste{
        public static void main(String[] args){

            Carro c1 = new Carro("00-AA-00");
            Carro c2 = new Carro("99-AA-99");

            ListaCarros l1 = new ListaCarros();
            l1.adicionar(c2);
            l1.adicionar(c1);

            Pessoa p1 = new Pessoa("Afonso", l1);

            //Como poderei fazer isto?
            //c1.getPessoa().getNome(); 


        }
    }
```

Como poderei ir buscar o nome do proprietário?

A única solução será colocar mais um parâmetro com o nome do prorietário?

Comment: De alguma forma você teria de ter uma referência para a Pessoa dentro do objeto Carro, para ele saber quem é o "pai". Não há mecanismo embutido na linguagem para saber quem detém uma referência a um objeto, e mesmo que tivesse, poderia haver mais de um "pai", poderia haver uma referência numa variável local, etc. Sugiro também abolir a classe ListaCarros e incorporar sua funcionalidade à classe Pessoa, para que o próprio método adicionar() já atribua Pessoa ao Carro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existem várias maneiras de resolver seu problema:

### Mínima modificação

Para essa possiblidade tentei modificar o mínimo do seu código para que você possa entender melhor. Você deve ligar a `Pessoa` ao `Carro`:

1. `Pessoa` deveria ter somente o nome como propriedade.
2. `ListaCarros` ao adicionar, precisa do parâmetro `Pessoa`. E a `HashMap` é de `<Pessoa, List<Carro>>`.

Código:

```
class Pessoa {
    private String nome;

    public Pessoa(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
}

class ListaCarros {
    private Map<Pessoa, List<Carro>> listaCarros = new HashMap<>();

    public void adicionar(Pessoa pessoa, Carro carro) {
        if (listaCarros.containsKey(pessoa)) {
            List<Carro> list = listaCarros.get(pessoa);
            list.add(carro);
            listaCarros.put(pessoa, list);
        } else {
            List<Carro> carros = new ArrayList<>();
            carros.add(carro);
            listaCarros.put(pessoa, carros);
        }
    }

    public Pessoa getPessoa(Carro carro) {
        for (Map.Entry<Pessoa, List<Carro>> entry : listaCarros.entrySet()) {
            Pessoa key = entry.getKey();
            List<Carro> value = entry.getValue();
            if (value.contains(carro)) {
                return key;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}

class Carro {

    private String matricula;

    public Carro(String matricula) {
        this.matricula = matricula;
    }

    public String getMatricula() {
        return matricula;
    }

}

public class Teste {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Carro c1 = new Carro("00-AA-00");
        Carro c2 = new Carro("99-AA-99");
        Pessoa p1 = new Pessoa("Afonso");

        ListaCarros l1 = new ListaCarros();
        l1.adicionar(p1, c2);
        l1.adicionar(p1, c1);

        System.out.println(l1.getPessoa(c1).getNome());
    }
}
```

**NOTE**: Código pode ser mais simples e compacto, mas deixei assim para você entender o que eu fiz.

### Outras possibilidades

Para deixar o seu código melhor, alguns cenários:

1. Remova o uso da classe `ListaCarros`
2. Analise o que é mais importante no seu código: o `Carro` ou a `Pessoa`.

   - Se for `Carro`, faça para cada `Carro` uma lista de `Pessoa`
   - Se for `Pessoa`, faça para cada `Pessoa` uma lista de `Carro`.
3. Dependendo do seu objeto, leve em consideração que terá que implementar os dois métodos abaixo para procurar na lista:

```
    public int hashCode();
    public boolean equals(Object o);
```